# Microsd card can't be read after being used with android phone once

Tags: external-sd, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have a Samsung galaxy s8.  I was using an external card reader to access a micro sd card.  Initially it worked fine, but lately I have been having some odd behavior.  The first time I connect the card reader to the phone, it works fine, I can access files on the microsd card.  However if disconnect and reconnect the the microsd card, it isn't detected.  If I attach the card reader to a windows PC, it says an error was detected and scan the drive.  Generally if I restart the phone, it detects the card again.

I'm at a loss for what's going on.  To complicate matters, I am not trying to read the sd card internally.  I am using a USB-c to USB-a adapter to connect the phone to an SD card reader and I am using an SD to Microsd adapter.  I have tried multiple usb-c to usb-a cables, and multiple micro sd - sd card adapters.  Both USB-C to USB-A cables are the same type, so it could still be some wort of cable issue, but I don't think so.

This isn't something I am using for phone storage, I have some trail cameras and the microSD cards are from them.  I want to be able to access the pictures on the microsd card in the field and copy the images to my phone storage.

This seems more like a software issue than a hardware issue, but I'm not completely sure.  I know android 9 (which is what my phone has) is getting pretty old, so I'm not sure if that's the issue, but it seems like it could be.

Comment: Use `parted`/`gdisk` to check the partitioning on the card. But first make sure that your card reader isn't broken.

Comment: You may need to recreate the partitions on the SD-card as Irfan mentioned. On Windows use the `Disk Management` (diskmgmt.msc) to view existing partitions on the card. Delete the existing one and create a new one using a suitable file-system (NTFS, exFat, FAT32). https://superuser.com/questions/1223640/where-is-my-disk

Comment: @IrfanLatif the card reader works fine with repeated insertions/removals on a PC.  I can remove the card reader or the card reader multiple times on the PC and it reads fine.  Its only an issue the first time I read the card after using on my phone
.

Comment: @Robert The partition seems fine, its a 32GB partition formatted with FAT32, not my first choice of file system, but its what works with the camera.  Windows scans the partition the first time I switch from my phone to PC, but doesn't find any errors, and then I am able to access the sd card.  Im not super concerned about windows reporting an issue, im more annoyed that the drive seems to be only readable once on my phone without restarting the phone.